# Unable to receive notification

Tags: ios, notifications

I try to send local notification. Here some code for class sending the notification:

```
@interface Sender : UIView
{
    NSInteger itemID;
} 

@implementation Sender

-(void) changedProperty
{
    [[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] postNotificationName:@"NotificationName" object:NULL];
}
```

And here the code to receive this notification:

```
@interface Listener : UIViewController
{

}

@implementation Listener
- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    [super viewDidLoad];        

    [[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] addObserver:self selector:@selector(selectedItem:) name:@"NotificationName" object:NULL];
}

- (void)viewDidUnload
{
    [super viewDidUnload];

    [[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] removeObserver:self name:@"NotificationName" object:NULL];
}

-(void) selectedItem:(NSNotification *) notification
{
    // some actions
}
```

But this code doesn't work. Debugging I see how **postNotificationName: object** works but the method **selectedItem:** doesn't call

**UPDATE.**
Here is more code. Maybe this will help.

```
extern const NSString* selectItemNotificationName;    
@interface vRoomSelectorItem : UIView
{
    RoomSelectorItemBackground backgroundType; 
    NSInteger itemID;
}
@property NSInteger itemID;
-(void) setBackgroundType:(RoomSelectorItemBackground) backgroundType;

@interface vRoomSelectorItem ()
@property RoomSelectorItemBackground backgroundType;
@end

@implementation vRoomSelectorItem

const NSString* selectItemNotificationName = @"Reservation.SelectRoom";

-(RoomSelectorItemBackground) backgroundType
{
    return backgroundType;
}
-(void) setBackgroundType:(RoomSelectorItemBackground)value
{
    if(backgroundType != value)
    {
        backgroundType = value;
        [self changedBackgroundType];
    }
}
-(void) changedBackgroundType
{
    if(backgroundType == RoomSelectorItemFilled)
    {
        // animation
        dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^{
            [[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] postNotificationName:(NSString*)selectItemNotificationName object:NULL userInfo:[[NSDictionary alloc] initWithObjectsAndKeys:[NSNumber numberWithInteger:itemID], @"ID", NULL]];
        });
    }
    else
        // reverse animation  
}

#import "vRoomSelectorItem.h"
    @interface vcReservationSelectRoom : UIViewController
{
    NSMutableArray* arraySelectorItems;
}        

@implementation vcReservationSelectRoom

- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    [super viewDidLoad];    

    [[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] addObserver:self selector:@selector(selectedItem:) name:(NSString*)selectItemNotificationName object:NULL];        

    for(NSInteger i = 1; i <= SELECTOR_ITEM_COUNT; ++i)
    {
        vRoomSelectorItem* newItem = [[vRoomSelectorItem alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(/*coordinates*/)];
        [self.view addSubview:newItem];            
        [newItem setBackgroundType:RoomSelectorItemTransparent];
        [newItem setItemID:i];
        [arraySelectorItems addObject:newItem];
        newItem = NULL;
    }
}

-(void) selectedItem:(NSNotification *) notification
{
    // some actions
}

-(void) dealloc
{    
    arraySelectorItems = NULL;
    [[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] removeObserver:self name:(NSString*)selectItemNotificationName object:NULL];
}
@end
```

Comment: when do you post the notification? is it **after** or **before** you've added the observer?

Comment: I has checked it. The observer was added before posting the notification

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, I've solved the problem. The piece of code above is not enough to understand, why it has not been working. The object of class **vcReservationSelectRoom** was temporary and it had been destroyed before sending notification from any **vRoomSelectorItem**. Sorry for my mistake of not showing enough code to solve this problem. And thank you all for helping.

Answer (score 0):

It seems like your code should work.  Make sure the notification is on the main thread and the workflow is as follows:

1. Add listener to notification center
2. Initiate sender
3. Send notification

You can be sure that it is on the main thread with:

```
dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^{
    [[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] post...];
});
```

Couple things I would change:

- remove yourself from `NSNotificationCenter` in `-(void)dealloc` instead
  of `-(void)viewDidUnload`. viewDidUnload will be deprecated, and
  dealloc could get called without viewDidUnload.
- For Notifications, I like to store the name in an external constant
  to make sure that I don't typo the string:

  ```
  //header.h
  extern NSString *const notificationName;


  //implementation.m
  NSString *const notificationName = @"notification";
  ```

Comment: Thx for your tips. The workflow is like you have described. But how could I make sure that notification is on the main thread? In this app I do not create any thread mannually. So it should be in the main thread.

Comment: Just has checked. Unfortunately it is still not working. I can't understand why it is so.

Comment: try retyping the selectors and notifications.  nine out of ten times the problem is a typo

Comment: Selectors and notifications are correct. Added more code in the topic. Hoping it would be useful

Answer (score 0):

From your code in the quetion I think you can try this:

```
- (void)viewDidLoad
```

{

```
[super viewDidLoad];        

[[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] addObserver:self selector:@selector(selectedItem:) name:@"NotificationName" object:NULL];

[self.view changedProperty]; // method of your Sender class

}
```

Comment: It's useless for me because method **changedProperty** is an internal method of class Sender